# SimpleFacebook.getInstance() return null

Tags: android, facebook, android-simple-facebook

just found [this](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) great library!

make all preparations, all the same as in repo wiki.

here is my code for btn login:

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn_sort_fb)
    public void onFbClecked(){
        if (!mIsFbSortActive){
            SimpleFacebook fb = SimpleFacebook.getInstance();
            new LoginWithFb(getActivity(), this, fb);
        }
    }
```

but `SimpleFacebook.getInstance();`return me `null`

looks like i am missing something...

will be glad any help!

Comment: Library you linked provides sample. Is sample working ?

Comment: As per the library, there two methods for getting the `SimpleFacebook.getInstance();` instance, one is return the `SimpleFacebook` object and other one which is without `params` is returning just the instance. use `SimpleFacebook fb = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CONTEXT);`

Comment: yes, one of them asking for an activity, another not. so which one I need to use?

Comment: ok, few min please, will try

Comment: The one which asking for activity context, because it initializes everything for the first use

Comment: thanks!
really my fault... )

Comment: Posting as an answer, so others could benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the library, there two methods for getting the `SimpleFacebook.getInstance();` instance, one is return the SimpleFacebook object and initializes the library where as the other one which is without param is returning just the instance.

Use

```
SimpleFacebook fb = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CONTEXT);
```

Source: [SimpleFacebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/blob/master/simple-fb/src/main/java/com/sromku/simple/fb/SimpleFacebook.java#L154)